# can i write two call back function in single service in android app

Tags: android

Could I add two call back function in single back ground service in android API..like i came to know that LocationManager is not working on all android mobile so some advised to use FusedLocationProviderApi library in android API.so can I write one background service in which two method be used.so any one of two could work,but don't know which will work when one is already in progress using listener.Basic thing is can i add extra normal or call back function with a call back function,It will work?

my code is below :

```
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.HttpStatus;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

//changes - start for fused location
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
//import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
//changes end for fused location with one comment above library

public class LocationService extends Service implements ConnectionCallbacks,
        GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
    public static final String BROADCAST_ACTION = "Hello World";
    public LocationManager locationManager;
    public MyLocationListener listener;
    public Location previousBestLocation = null;
    Intent intent;
    int counter = 0;

    //fused changes -- start
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener  mGoogleListener;
    //fused chhanges - end

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        intent = new Intent(BROADCAST_ACTION);

        //fused changes --start
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();

        //fused changes -- end
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent,int flag, int startId)
    {
        //first call LocationManager 
                try {
                    int time = 2 * 60 * 1000;
                    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                    listener = new MyLocationListener();
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, time, 0, listener);
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, time, 0, listener);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    String error = e.getMessage();
                }

                //second call --fused class - start
                try {
                    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                          .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                        .setInterval(10 * 1000)        // 10 seconds, in milliseconds
                      .setFastestInterval(1 * 1000); // 1 second, in milliseconds
                    //LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, listener);

                    //fused location --end
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    String error = e.getMessage();
                }

            return Service.START_STICKY;
        } catch (Exception e){
            stopService(new Intent(LocationService.this,LocationService.class));
            return Service.START_STICKY;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // handler.removeCallbacks(sendUpdatesToUI);
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.v("STOP_SERVICE", "DONE");
        locationManager.removeUpdates(listener);
    }

    public static Thread performOnBackgroundThread(final Runnable runnable) {
        final Thread t = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    runnable.run();
                } finally {

                }
            }
        };
        t.start();
        return t;
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        try {
        //tried with pending intent but not working
            //LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, PendingIntent.getService(this, 1, new Intent(this, MyLocationListener.class), 0));
        //tried with mGooogleListener
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,mLocationRequest, mGoogleListener);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            String error = e.getMessage();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    //when fused library detect location change - gets here do whatever want to do
        double locLat = location.getLatitude();
        double locLong = location.getLongitude();
    }


    public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener
    {
        class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... uri) {
                String responseString = null;
                return responseString;
            }


            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
            }
        }

        public void onLocationChanged(final Location loc)
        {
        //when locationManager detect location change, then gets here , now do whatever want to do
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
        {
            //Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Gps Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        }


        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
        {
            //Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Gps Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
        {

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking, and from the lack of responses it seems like others don't either. Could you give an example of what you're trying to do? It would be ideal if you could try to solve the problem yourself and, when you come across a specific problem, post the details here - that will be a lot easier to answer!

Comment: Hi Jordan, thanks for your reply.I tried to solve problem myself,but was in kind of logical issue.My problem is I want to get location in every possible case.But I came to know that in some mobile locationManager is not able to give location and some suggested fusedLibrary.So i tried to implement both classes code in single background service.But both give location through callBack function.So was not able to understand how to do that.What will happen if both callBack function were called simultaneously.I tried many things but ended with nothing.

Comment: I'd strongly encourage you to post some code as that would make it a lot easier to make a concrete suggestion for how to help. Without that, I can only make vague statements: it sounds like you want your background service to make calls to two different services, wait for the callbacks for these two services, and then figure out which callback contains the data you want to use. Then your service will, in turn, call its own callback to the Activity (or whatever is calling your service).

Comment: I have written above code in background service.I picked locationManager working code from net. and it was running fine on some android device.then I added fused library code for rest deviice.but its not working.